# Why the uniform representation of immediate values in GC'd languages?

Tags: memory, garbage-collection

...Or is the correlation not a causation?
It seems to be the norm that garbage collected languages follow the lisp tradition of having all values be machine word sized—even smaller values like bytes and short ints.
It is only the exception when they deviate from that, and usually within another (boxed) data structure like a bytestring or array, for more compact memory usage. In many cases that optimization is even hardcoded in the language and there is not a first-class facility that the users of the language can exploit to represent their data with less padding.

So my question is, why is it like that? Is there something inherent to GC performance, or the way a tracing GC is architected, when all values are of the same size.. that goes away as soon as we have different sized values? Are there counter examples of garbage collectors that handle non-uniform data?

Comment: One reason could be memory align. I didn't enforced it in my GC but it maybe done by undelaying malloc anyway.

Comment: Your question suggests that a different behavior was the norm with non-GC languages. Is it? How many languages with a different behavior, besides C/C++, do you know?

Comment: I admit I had C in mind, and that's the only one I have some experience with. and even then, such compactness makes sense for compound data, but not so much for single values (they might be even word-aligned on the stack for all I know).. Besides C I only know of Fortran, Ada, and Rust that don't abstract away the layout of a type (there are others I can guess do the same like D, crystal, nim, zig, but I don't know enough about them to know for sure), and for those three I don't know how they behave with the stack, single values, etc...

Comment: I think, uniform data representation in a stack frame for gc efficiency could have been kept as an implementation detail, without a need to specify it in a language. The rules made in languages like Java were designed for simplicity (similar to dropping unsigned types which surely doesn’t affect gc). So, appearing alongside gc is just coincidence, though both aim at making programming easier.